# How to enable Windows authentication with server side Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, iis, blazor

I have a Blazor Server-side application which uses Windows Authentication using IIS. The application is hosted on IIS and I've changed the Identity of the website of the application pools to a system service account. (Say it's `Domain\sys_account`).

The following code is in `LoginDisplay.razor`. It can display the correct Identity of the user who opens the web page.

```
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        @{
            var identity = (System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity)context.User.Identity;
        }
        Hello, @identity!
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        You are not authorized.
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

I need to get the current identity in the C# code. So the following class and interface are created.

```
public interface ICurrentUserService
{
    string UserId { get; }
}

public class CurrentUserService : ICurrentUserService
{
    public CurrentUserService()
    {
        UserId = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
    }

    public string UserId { get; }
}
```

And it's added to services as

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // ....
        services.AddScoped<ICurrentUserService, CurrentUserService>();
```

However, in the following code. `_currentUserService.UserId` is `Domain\sys_account` instead of the id of the person who accesses the site? How to get the identity of current logged in user?

```
public class RequestLogger<TRequest> : IRequestPreProcessor<TRequest>
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly ICurrentUserService _currentUserService;

    public RequestLogger(ILogger<TRequest> logger, ICurrentUserService currentUserService)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _currentUserService = currentUserService; // _currentUserService.UserId is Domain\sys_account instead of the id of the person who accesses the site?
    }

    public Task Process(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var name = typeof(TRequest).Name;

        _logger.LogInformation("Request: {Name} {@UserId} {@Request}",
            name, _currentUserService.UserId, request); // _currentUserService.UserId is Domain\sys_account instead of the id of the person logged in?

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: That should help : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#authenticationstateprovider-service

Answer (score 3):

Perform the following to enable Windows authentication on Blazor and ASP.NET Core Controllers for IIS and Kestrel (applies to ASP.NET Core 3.1 and ASP.NET 5):

1. Add nuget references:

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization

2. update Startup.cs

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();
// Windows authentication  may not be applied with Kestrel without this line
services.AddAuthorization(options => options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy);

...

// Add the following below app.UseRouting()
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

3. the rest is the same as with using other authentication methods.

A full example if provided below, stars are welcome :)

[Blazor and ASP.NET Core controller using Windows authentication](https://github.com/akovac35/TestingBlazor)